# omp for loop for constexpr indexes

Tags: c++, for-loop, templates, openmp, constexpr

Suppose I have a function depending on a nontype template argument, an `std::size_t`, which can take value `0,...,N-1`, with `N` known at compile time.
An iteration over all values can be done with a `std::sequence` or with a template recursion. E.g.:

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t I>
void f() {
//...
}

template <std::size_t... I>
void loop_f_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
   (f<I>(),...);
}

template <std::size_t N>
void loop_f() {
   loop_f_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
   constexpr std::size_t N = 4;
   loop_f<N>();
}
```

How can I convert the "unrolled loop" to a standard for loop that I can parallelize with openmp? Something like that (which obviously does not compile...)

```
#pragma omp for
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
     f<i>();
```

Clearly, if, say, N=3, I could implement that with

```
#pragma omp for
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
             f<1>();
             break;
        case 2:
             f<2>();
             break;
        case 3:
             f<3>();
             break;
    }
```

I am interested however in a generic code that works for every `N`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that what you're asking, but can't you just store all the functions into array and call them in omp loop?
https://godbolt.org/z/f7vbPMeqE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> omp for loop for `constexpr` indexes

You could change `f` to take `I` as an argument instead since `i` in your `for` loop is *not* `constexpr` and can't be used where one is needed.

```cpp
void f(std::size_t I) {
}
```

Another option, without using omp, could be to launch all `f<I...>()`s asynchronously:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t... I>
void loop_f_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::tuple all{ std::async(std::launch::async, f<I>)... };
} // here all futures stored in the `tuple` wait until done
```

---

An alternative could be to use one of the standard (since C++17) [*Execution Policies*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) directly from `loop_f` in a `std::for_each`. Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <execution>

template <std::size_t N>
void loop_f() {
    // C++20 lambda template:
    constexpr auto funcs = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array{f<Is>...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, funcs.begin(), funcs.end(),
                  [](auto func) { func(); });
}
```

This will make use of *Intel® oneAPI Threading Building Blocks* or whatever your implementation uses as a backend.

Comment: The first solution is not a possibility (actual code for f needs in several places a constexpr I). The second solution is actually a good suggestion (though perhaps Intel TBB might perform better than std::threads, but that's another aspect). Thanks!

Comment: @francesco You're welcome! I haven't worked with TBB directly, only indirectly when using _execution policies_ in standard algorithms. I added an alternative solution using those.